# Advanced Custom Field doesn't show in wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have this bit of code that doesn't render on page. Does anybody know what the issue is?

```
<div class="b b--alt">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tab-widget tab-widget--team js-tab-widget">
      <?php if( have_rows('the_commusoft_story') ) { ?>
        <?php $i = 0; ?>
        <ul class="tab-widget__list">
        <?php while( have_rows('the_commusoft_story') ): the_row(); ?>
          <?php $i++ ?>
                        <li class="tab-widget__item">
            <a href="#tab-panel-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="tab-widget__link">
                              <span class="ss-icon <?php the_sub_field('icon'); ?>"></span>
                              <h2><?php the_sub_field('section_title'); ?></h2>
                              <?php the_sub_field('section_description'); ?>
            </a>
          </li>
                      <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
                <?php }; ?>
      <?php if( have_rows('the_commusoft_story') ) { ?>
        <?php $i = 0; ?>
        <div class="tab-widget__tabs">
          <?php while( have_rows('the_commusoft_story') ): the_row(); ?>
          <?php $i++ ?>
            <div class="tab-widget__tab-content">
            <h2 id="tab-panel-<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php the_sub_field('section_title'); ?></h2>
            <?php the_sub_field('content'); ?>
          </div>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
      <?php }; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SO on the page are two sections, the problem appears when I try to move it as second section and it disappears...

Any idea what is going on, and where the mistake is?

Thanks

Comment: can u provide the link?

Answer (score 0):

Your code can definately be simplified. I've removed the extra IF statement - it's not required. I've also added line terminations to the `$i++` operators:

```
<div class="b b--alt">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="tab-widget tab-widget--team js-tab-widget">
            <?php if( have_rows('the_commusoft_story') ) : ?>
                <?php $i = 0; ?>
                <ul class="tab-widget__list">
                    <?php while( have_rows('the_commusoft_story') ): the_row(); ?>
                        <?php
                        $i++; // This starts at 1.
                        ?>

                        <li class="tab-widget__item">
                            <a href="#tab-panel-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="tab-widget__link">
                                <span class="ss-icon <?php the_sub_field('icon'); ?>"></span>
                                <h2><?php the_sub_field('section_title'); ?></h2>
                                <?php the_sub_field('section_description'); ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>

                <?php $i = 0; ?>
                <div class="tab-widget__tabs">
                    <?php while( have_rows('the_commusoft_story') ): the_row(); ?>
                        <?php
                        $i++;
                        ?>
                        <div class="tab-widget__tab-content">
                            <h2 id="tab-panel-<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php the_sub_field('section_title'); ?></h2>
                            <?php the_sub_field('content'); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>

            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This, in theory, should be a working piece of code. So - if what I have written doesn't work for you; I'd advise checking for PHP errors, or possibly looking for CSS styling conflicts.

Keep us posted how you get on :)